# How can I pin an element to the bottom of a div with flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am having trouble getting an element to stick to the bottom of a div with flexbox, or by any other means in a way that works well.

So far I've tried:

1. adding margin-top:auto; to the last div
2. adding margin-bottom:auto; to the p tag above the last div
3. align-self: flex-end; to the last div
4. position: absolute; bottom: 0; to the last div
5. switching to css grid
6. wrapping the elements I want at the top of the container in their own div
7. align-self to each element individually
8. height: 100%; to the p tag above the last div

```css
.outer-div {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: baseline;
  border: 3px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh
}

.element {
  margin: 0px auto 0px 0px;
  align-self: baseline;
}

.par {
  flex: 100%
}

.buttons {
  flex: 100% margin: auto 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-div">
  <p class="element" href="">element</p>
  <small class="other-element">element</small>
  <p class="par">word</p>
  <div class="buttons">
    <button>button 1</button>
    <button>button 2</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

1. any margin that was there to begin with collapsed
2. any margin that was there to begin with collapsed
3. it did nothing.
4. it almost worked but it covered some of the content.
5. pushes some of the content outside of the div.
6. didn't change anything.
7. the p tag wouldn't stretch fully.
8. pushed the last element outside of the div.

Comment: Which of your elements should be stuck to the bottom of the div?

Comment: @j08691 The div with class of buttons.

Comment: Like this https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/mdcvzaw3/?

Comment: @j08691 Close but if there are to many words in <p class="par"> then the buttons will cover them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switch to `flex-direction: column`, so that the main axis is vertical, and use `margin-top: auto` on the buttons.

```css
.outer-div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh
}

.buttons {
  margin-top: auto;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-div">
  <p class="element" href="">element</p>
  <small class="other-element">element</small>
  <p class="par">word</p>
  <div class="buttons">
    <button>button 1</button>
    <button>button 2</button>
  </div>
</div>
```